# SKSpriteNode subclass and touches events

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I can't understand why if I subclass a SKSpriteNode, that implements the UIResponder protocol, the methods related with touches are never been called.

For example, this is a really simple class that I'm using as test:

```
//INTERFACE ----------------
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface TestClass : SKSpriteNode

@end

//IMPLEMENTATION -----------
#import "TestClass.h"

@implementation TestClass


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     NSLog(@"oook");
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}

@end
```

If I attach an instance of this class to the scene, touching the object... nothing happens.

Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've just seen that SKNode has the parameter `userInteractionEnabled` by default equal to `NO`. Just set it to `YES` to make the code works properly.

Comment: but if its covered by a sprite that doesnt have interaction enabled the covering sprite swallows the touches...

Comment: @Smick, do you mean that it's possible to tap "through" covering sprites if they have userinteractionEnabled = YES ?

Comment: I just tried this and it doesnt seem matter if the covering sprite has userInteractionEnabled or not, it will block the touches to the sprite below anyway. I would love to find a way around this behaviour, as I want transparent cloud moving in the forground.

Comment: i saw that you have seen the other post, but if your try my answer you can see that the scene can loop through all nodes at that point, so the covering sprite will detect a hit! But the actual nodes beginTouch isnt called.

Comment: @bobmoff how about to set `zPosition` to `10000` for the button? That probably will work

Comment: @AndreyGordeev that makes the button render on top of the "covering" sprite which defeats the purpose of having a covering sprite, coz then it is not covering any more. I acctually wrote a post about this and put my solution up on gist https://gist.github.com/bobmoff/7110052. I dont know if its ok post links to self written blog posts :)

Comment: @AndreyGordeev could you kindly share with us your blog's post? It'd great! :)

Comment: @MatterGoal, I guess you ment my (@bobmoff) blogpost? The site isn't released yet, so there isnt a permanent link yet, but here goes: http://imgnry.com/blog.html

Comment: Yep, sorry @AndreyGordeev I meant bobmoff blog post.

Comment: So long as the node that implements `- (void)touchesBegan:withEvent:` has userInteractionEnabled set to true and its children nodes do not, the touches will be handled by the implementing node. If the child nodes have userInteractionEnabled true, then the touch is handled by them.

Comment: For anyone seeking the previously mentioned blog post (like myself), it can be found at http://imgnry.com/blog/fixing-the-broken-touch-behaviour-in-spritekit